# Link to a service contained in third party library(jar)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I know and have tried creating system services in android as described here : http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService

The question is regarding how to use a third party jar placed in frameworks which contains the service implementation. AIDL files are provided which exposes the functions of the service.

My question is, after building the source, how can I bind to the service from a third party app, provided the following in source tree:

(1) `jar - Linux/android/vendor/companyname/libs/frameworks`

(2) `AIDL - Linux/android/frameworks/base/core/java/ny/co/companyname/bluetooth/api`

Please let me know if any clarifications regarding the above mentioned is required.

Any help is much appreciated

**PS:**

For testing, we used the lib(jar) and AIDL as part of an android application,and we can see the service getting bound correctly using bindservice, by observing the logs inside `onServiceConnected` callback.

Answer (score 1):

For services to work correctly, the stub must be generated in the R.java file.

Now here (might be because of ADT bug), for generating stub definition in R.java file, you will have to keep the AIDL file in your src folder with the same named package.

In your case, in your project's src folder, create a package

Linux/android/frameworks/base/core/java/ny/co/companyname/bluetooth/api

and place your AIDL file in it.

You might meet the fate. :)